# Is there a way to arrange images without using an inline element in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create a PDF with precisely arranged images using Apache FOP, but due to the nature of inline elements and line-height calculations, I am finding it challenging to arrange the graphics precisely where I want them (due to the [surrounding whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722640/unwanted-margin-after-foexternal-graphic)) by default.

I know I can do things like this to help:

```xml
    <fo:block
      padding-bottom="{$height}"
      font-size="0pt"
      line-height="0pt"
    >
      <fo:external-graphic
        vertical-align="top"
        height="{$height}"
        width="{$width}"
        src="/path/to/img.png"
      />
    </fo:block>
```

but in the end I find that the `vertical-align` property tends to be unpredictable and the whole workaround confuses intent.

Is there another another way to embed images and handle layout like block elements so I can simply specify a width/height/margin/padding and be done with it?

*Note: I am fairly new to xsl-fo, with a background in HTML/CSS*

Comment: There is not enough information for anyone to answer this. You should show a complete, minimal FO file and some screen shot of what is wrong with a description of what would be right.

Comment: What I'm asking for is an alternative way to add an image to a PDF where I can specify width and height and have the image take the exact dimensions I specify - the example is meant to illustrate the image element I know about and why it isn't satisfactory. the block happens to be a child element of `<fo:block-container />`, but that isn't relevant to my problem.